# Android Handler not updating textview

Tags: android, textview, handler

Thought I would share some weird code with you all to see if I have done anything blindingly wrong. 
I have passed a handler to a background thread to update the UI of the mainactivity (I know it is not the best way but this is supposed to be a quick and dirty test app)
Basically, the code appends a message on to the textview, like so:

```
                    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.i("Text2Server", "Updating log with: " + logput);
                        logTextView.append(logput);
                    }
                });
```

This happens everytime a UDP message is received, the log is output everytime perfectly, but the textview only updates on the first message, or sometimes not at all.

I assume it is something to do with my textview but I thought I would see if anyone has seen anything similar?

Thanks!

P.S. I have tried the basics, like using setText() instead of append() etc.

Comment: Also having this issue. It works on the first load but reloading the activity it no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Does it output `"Text2Server", "Updating log with: " + logput` in the LogCat?

`.post(Runnable r)` this runnable is placed on the queue and will be run later when the thread that is attached executes.

Maybe, the handler does not gain access to the ui thread, this assumption can be wrong as well.

Try another way.

Instantiate the handler:

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(){

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {        
        String logPutFromThread=msg.getData().getString("somekey");
            Log.i("Text2Server", "Updating log with: " + logPutFromThread);
            logTextView.append(logPutFromThread);
        }

    };
```

and from the `Runnable` of the thread do

```
Runnable updateActivityUi = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

        //do something before you send the message
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.peekData().putString("somekey", logput)
                handler.sendMessage(msg)


        }};
```

Comment: Yeah, the log is shown and the textview just doesnt update. It is weird.

Comment: Nope, trying it now though. Will post with results, sorry for the delay.

Comment: OK, still doesn't work. The handler does not get called and nothing is logged. I think I remember having this problem before and it being something to do with Loopers, but I am not sure. Any ideas?
Thanks for your help so far!